# Produce Optional Beans in CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want do create a CDI factory using `@Produces` annotation on a method in order to look up a named something in an external service and return (produce) a proxy to this something in the external service to be injected into other beans. From a use case point of view, usually all these dependencies are required; however it happens sometimes that the requested something does not exist in the remote service and the application can react to this fact.

Basically the structure is like this:

```java
@Singleton public class SomeBean {
  @Inject @MyName("required") private Something requiredSomething;
  @Inject @MyName("optional") private Instance<Something> optionalSomething;

  @PostConstruct void init() {
    if (optionalSomething.isUnSatisfied()) {
      // act without optional Something in external service
    } else {
      optionalSomething.get().doWhatIWant(NOW);
    }
  }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SomethingFactory {
  @Inject private RemoteSomethingService remoteService;

  @Produces
  @MyName(value = "")
  public Something createRemoteSomething(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    MyName name = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(MyName.class);
    Something some = remoteService.lookup(name.value()); // throws an exception if lookup fails
    return some;
  }
}
```

This works in cases the injection on the side that uses somethings is required: successfull lookups inject the looked up `Something` instance, while unsuccessful lookups break the bean bootstrapping. However, in cases of an optional injection with a non-existent something, it either breaks because `Instance.isUnSatisfied()` returns `false`. If I leave `createRemoteSomething()` throwing the exception, this exception is raised during the call to `optionalSomething.get()`; if I return `null` instead, the same call leads to a NPE.

How to achieve this using CDI primitives? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your producer method is just fine (I'm assuming its return type is supposed to be `Something`).  You are producing a `Something` in `@Dependent` scope (the default).

Things that are in `@Dependent` scope may be `null`.  In general nothing else may be.  (There are some leftover bits in CDI from ancient times when other scopes could produce `null` objects but they are the remnants of a bygone era.)

So in your case, simply return `null` from your producer method when you cannot produce what you want, but this is not an error condition (otherwise obviously throw an exception of some kind).

Then, on the consuming side, you're almost there.

`Instance#isUnsatisfied()` returns `true` only when there is no producer method (or other kind of bean) that can "make" the thing being asked for.  In your case, there *is* a producer method that can "make" the thing being asked for, so `isUnsatisfied()` returns `false`, and that is proper.

All you should have to do is change this:

```
optionalSomething.get().doWhatIWant(NOW);
```

…to:

```
final Something something = optionalSomething.get();
if (something == null) {
  // no such Something, but an expected case
} else {
  something.doWhatIWant(NOW);
}
```

Again, this only works if `Something` is in `@Dependent` scope (and not, say, `@ApplicationScoped` scope) which in your case is indeed the case.